# TypeError TypeError: post_route() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post_slug'

Tags: python, html, flask, web-development-server

I am new in flask I am try to make a blog but when I try to open a post from my database at that time this type of error was thrown.
Here is code file.

The full error is

TypeError
TypeError: post_route() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post_slug'

Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: post_route() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post_slug'
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object

**flask**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Mail
import json
from datetime import datetime


with open('config.json', 'r') as c:
    params = json.load(c)["params"]

local_server = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    MAIL_PORT = '465',
    MAIL_USE_SSL = True,
    MAIL_USERNAME = params['gmail-user'],
    MAIL_PASSWORD=  params['gmail-pass']
)
mail = Mail(app)
if(local_server):
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = params['local_url']
else:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = params['prod_uri']

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Contact(db.Model):
    sr = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    phone= db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False)
    msg = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)


class Posts(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(21), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    tagline = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
    img_file = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    posts = Posts.query.filter_by().all()[0:params['no_of_posts']]
    return render_template('index.html', params=params, posts=posts)


@app.route("/post/", methods=['GET'])
def post_route(post_slug):
    post = Posts.query.filter_by(slug=post_slug).first()
    return render_template('post.html', params=params, post=post)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', params=params)


@app.route("/contact", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        name = request.form.get('name')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        phone = request.form.get('phone')
        message = request.form.get('message')
        entry = Contact(name=name, phone= phone, msg = message, date= datetime.now(),email = email )
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()
        mail.send_message('New message from ' + name,
                          sender=email,
                          recipients = [params['gmail-user']],
                          body = message + "\n" + phone
                          )
    return render_template('contact.html', params=params)


app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <!-- Page Header -->
    <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='img/home-bg.jpg') }}')">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="site-heading">
              <h1>{{params['blog_name']}}</h1>
              <span class="subheading">{{params['tag_line']}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">


     <!-- Todo: Fetch it using for loop from the database -->

     {% for post in posts %}    
          <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="/post/{{post.slug}}">
              <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}

              </h2>
              <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                {{post.tagline}}
              </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by
              <a href="#">Admin</a>
              on {{post.date}}</p>
          </div>

          {{post.content[0:143]}}...
          <hr>
</li></a>
          {% endfor %}


          <!-- Pager -->
          <div class="clearfix">
            <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="#">Older Posts →</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the trailing '/' in the post route.

Comment: now error is solved but its shows "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."   the url is "http://127.0.0.1:5000/post/first-post"

Comment: The post may not have been created yet, try creating a post first.